# Mobile App with Salesforce Integration using a static Login Credential

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios

Scenario: I am trying to build a Mobile APP, the Contacts of salesforce.com would be the user of that Mobile APP.

Suppose I am a contact in salesforce, and when I logged in Mobile APP, I need to see all my cases present in salesforce.

I do not have Community .

Question : Can I use a static Login credential to get authenticated with Salesforce and then fetch the case data related to different Contacts.
Is this the correct solution?

Answer (score 1):

No this is not a good approach .Rolling custom session management is never a good approach and each salesforce license comes with lot of security features .So ideally prefer using license rather than static credential .

> The session management is difficult without salesforce license .